# Como definir um #if ou #define condicionalmente?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Boa tarde pessoal...

Estou ajudando um pessoal a fazer um mod de jogo de PC compatível com sua versão Android (Stardew Valley). O problema é que preciso usar métodos que só existem na versão android para desenhar no HUD.

As duas versões do jogo possuem a mesma DLL, mas com alguns métodos diferentes.
Eu pensei em usar o `#if` e `#endif` para especificar esses métodos dentro sem dar erro de compilação, mas o problema é a definição desse if.

Como eu faço para especificar esse #if para ser processado só se for android?
Ou como eu poderia criar um #define condicional para o android?

PS. Criar uma versão para cada plataforma não é uma opção.

Comment: Você instalou o sdk do Android e configurou tudo certinho no seu projeto? O que não neu deu certo? Apresente um [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que esse trecho de código só seja executado quando se trata de um dispositivo android, você deve indicar no #if

```
#if __ANDROID__
// seu código para Android
#endif
```

Você pode inclusive, definir diferentes comportamentos para diferentes níveis de compatibilidade

```
#if __ANDROID_11__
// código para o Honeycomb e versões posteriores
#endif
```

Para mais informações, leia a documentação da Microsoft:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/platform-divergence-abstraction-divergent-implementation

Comment: Essa foi a primeira coisa que eu tentei e não funcionou =/